# How do we get to these steps in the equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have problems understanding whats happening between these steps.

$(P+1)(y-x) - 1(x) > 0$
$(P+1)(y) - (P+2) x > 0$
$x > y(P+1)/(P+2)$

Comment: Where exactly are you finding it difficult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(P+1)(y-x)-1x\gt0$

$(P+1)y-(P+1)x-1x\gt0$

$(P+1)y- Px -1x-1x\gt0$

$(P+1)y- Px -2x\gt0$

$(P+1)y- (P+2)x\gt0$

$- (P+2)x\gt-(P+1)y$

Now you divide with a negative number, so you have to change the $\gt$ to $\lt$.

$x\lt\frac{-(P+1)}{-(P+2)}y$

$x\lt\frac{P+1}{P+2}y$

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much.